# SendInBlue PHP API with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, sendinblue

I'm using the Codeigniter framework and trying to integrate with SendInBlue's PHP API. Their [PHP documentation](https://developers.sendinblue.com/docs) is not super helpful and the setup instructions on [Github](https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-php-library) not clear either.

The doc says to "Download the files and include autoload.php":

```
require_once('/path/to/APIv3-php-library/vendor/autoload.php');
```

But I cannot find `autoload` anywhere and I'm not really sure how to include that in my CI structure.

**Update:**

I contacted Sendinblue support and they do not have any installation tutorial for CI users. I tried using Compiler, and got the folder structure created but I'm still having issues integrating it with CI. I placed all the folders in my Libraries but it is not loaded correctly and complains about Autoload class not existing.

[image: Composer result]

Comment: do you use composer ? it looks like this autoload.php is composers autoload.php...

Comment: No, I don't really know what is composer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the autoload.php, you need to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). This will resolve all dependencies and install/update them for you.

If you already have the entire **SendInBlue API** folder structure in the library location, you can only add in your controller, before `class My_Class ...` line `require_once (APPPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php');`

eg.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

// include manually module library - SendInBlue API
require_once (APPPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php');

class My_Class extends CI_Controller {
....
```

After that, you can follow the guide from [Github: APIv3-php-library - Getting Started](https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-php-library#getting-started)

If you get errors, means that your SendInBlue's structure is bad. I recommand you to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

1. Install Composer if is not installed - [Installation - Linux / Unix / OSX](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) or [Installation - Windows](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows)
2. Install SendinBlue's API with Composer - [Github: APIv3-php-library - Installation & Usage](https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-php-library#installation--usage)
3. Add `autoload.php` in your controller - see the previous example

Please add here the list of errors if you still have issues.

Comment: It worked! Just made a few adjustments. In my controller the correct path is `require_once (APPPATH . 'libraries\vendor\autoload.php');` and I had to change autoload.php to `require_once (APPPATH . 'libraries\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php');` instead of the default `_DIR_ ...`

Answer (score 0):

I have a beautiful solution for this and it works fine for me and I hope it will work for you as well.
I am using API-v3.

What I did is:

1. Downloaded the API through composer on my local PC.
2. Created a folder named "sendinblue" on the server (where we have
   assets folders) and upload the vendor folder from the downloaded API
   inside this folder.
3. Created a library named "Sendinblue.php" and added all the necessary functions here. Now I can use this library like other libraries.

This is my library structure:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sendinblue{
    public $config;
    public $apiInstance;
    public function __construct(){      
        require_once('sendinblue/vendor/autoload.php');
        $this->config = SendinBlue\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('api-key', '');
        $this->apiInstance = new SendinBlue\Client\Api\ContactsApi(
            new GuzzleHttp\Client(),
            $this->config
        );      
    }

    public function get_contact_info($data){
        $identifier = $data['email'];
        try {
          return $result = $this->apiInstance->getContactInfo($identifier);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          return 'Exception when calling ContactsApi->getContactInfo: '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    
    public function create_contact($data){
        $createContact = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\CreateContact();
        $createContact['email'] = $data['email'];
        $createContact['listIds'] = [2];
        try {
          return $result = $this->apiInstance->createContact($createContact);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          return $e->getCode();
        }
    }
```